# 16-day-MODIS NDVI values seem to be wrong compared to my soil moisture ground data!

Tags: remote-sensing, modis, ndvi

I'm using MOD13Q1 product of MODIS for estimation soil moisture. As I know, this product is made up of the maximum value of NDVI of each pixel over 16-day calculated NDVI values. The problem is that my soil moisture in situ measurements don't correspond to the NDVI values. For example, where NDVI is 0.75, the calculated soil moisture is 0.2; in another case, where NDVI is 0.4, the soil moisture is 0.5, which is the highest value of soil moisture calculated. Of course, this problem doesn't occur for all the pixels.

For working with MODIS product, I use ENVI software. I first use MODIS Conversion Toolkit(MCTK) to transform its sinusoidal coordinate system into Geographic Lat/Long system. Then, I examine the NDVI values based on the location of my soil moisture ground measurements.

I know that my ground measurements are point-wise and the NDVI product covers around 250m * 250m on the ground, but soil water content over this area doesn't differ significantly. What's the problem in this case? where I'm making a mistake?

Comment: Are you in a study area where a relationship between soil moisture and NDVI is to be expected?

Comment: Do you have a lot of clouds in that area?

Comment: Since are using MOD13Q1 you should check its quality layer [(pixel reliability summary](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/dataset_discovery/modis/modis_products_table/mod13q1), not the daily one.

Comment: Thank you @Mikkel. Yes, some parts of the area had been obscured by clouds. Thank you @Kersten; I checked the reliability layer, and it seems some pixels I'm dealing with were influenced by clouds and then are not reliable! I'm out of luck!